# Grouping users and having permissions within groups

Tags: django

I have an application centered around CRUDing data for a relatively simple model. I would like to group users into "workgroups". Each "workgroup" has two types of users, "contributors" and "supervisors".

"Contributors" can CRUD their own data, but only read the data added by other members of the "workgroup". "Supervisors" can CRUD all data contributed by members of the "workgroup". "Workgroups" never interact with each other.

I thought about using the built in Groups and Permissions functionality, but it feels hacky, as groups seem to serve mostly to assign sets of permissions and permissions seem to be geared toward a per-model use case.

Of course, I could just have a boolean field for "contributor" vs. "supervisor" and a custom "Workgroup" model with a FK in my User model.

What would be the elegant way to solve this?

NB: the terms in quotes are application specific, just clarifying in case they conflict with any Django functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood correctly you have 2 level system:

1. Workgroups - are just for organisation purposes and has no direct relation to permissions,
2. user role - (contributor and supervisors) are permissions related.

Django Auth [Group model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#groups) can be used for one or other purpose or not at all:

A) Group == workgroups - in that case you should not manage permissions by using  groups. Each User needs to have assigned "contributor" or "supervisor" permission assigned, e.g.

```
some_group = Group.objects.create(name="Some workgroup")
user.groups.add(some_group)

sv_perm = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_supervise',...)
user.user_permissions.add(permission=sv_perm)
```

B) Group can serve as User role, in that case Workgroups should be custom model and you should have User.FK -> Workgroup.

```
some_workgroup = Workgroup.objects.create("some workgroup"...)
user.workgroup = some_workgroup

sv_perm = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_supervise',...)
sv_group = Group.objects.create(name="Supervisors")
sv_group.permissions.add(sv_perm)
user.groups.add(sv_group)
```

C) skip using Django auth Group - combination of A) and B), e.g.

```
some_workgroup = Workgroup.objects.create(name="Some workgroup")
user.workgroup = some_workgroup

sv_perm = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_supervise',...)
user.user_permissions.add(permission=sv_perm)
```

NOTE: this is not tested code, serves only as demonstration.

I feel the most comfortable with custom solution, so I would choose C) - the most flexible solution IMHO.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Meant to write this comment earlier... I ended up going with option C as I realized the Django groups are mostly centered around grouping users based on permissions (so, much like roles) and didn't fit elegantly into my concept of workgroup. Thanks again!